# How can I display a prompt information when I click summary area of ListPreference if entries is emptyArray<CharSequence>?

Tags: android

Sometimes the entries of ListPreference is  emptyArray, I hope to the system display a prompt information instead of popup a empty list dialog box when I click the area *android:summary="Choose backup item to restore".*

How can I do? Thanks!

```
  <ListPreference
            android:key="RestoreItem"
            android:title="Restore Item"
            android:summary="Choose backup item to restore"
   /> 


   fun setPreference(){          
            var aListPreference=preferenceManager.findPreference("RestoreItem") as ListPreference
            val entries = arrayOf<CharSequence>("English", "French")
            val entryValues = arrayOf<CharSequence>("1", "2")


            val aa = emptyArray<CharSequence>()
            var bb=  emptyArray<CharSequence>()


            aListPreference.entries=cc
            aListPreference.entryValues=dd

     }
```

BTW, the following code doesn't work, the system box still display empty list  box

```
 aListPreference.onPreferenceClickListener = OnPreferenceClickListener {
                var result=aListPreference.entries.size>=1

                if (result==false){
                    toast("There is no backup item")
                }

                result
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to custom your own `DialogPreference` with different content logic

(I am writing this in Java)

class `YourCustomDialogPreference`:

```
public AboutDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
    // Define buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton(null, null);
    builder.setNegativeButton(null, null);

    super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);
}

@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
    // Your view binding and content logic goes here
    mAboutList = view.findViewById(R.id.privacy_list);
    mAboutList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.layout_privacy_item, mPrivacyItems));
    mAboutList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    // bla bla ...

    super.onBindDialogView(view);
}
```

Define it in `preference.xml`:

```
<your.package.name.YourCustomDialogPreference
        android:key="pref_about"
        android:dialogLayout="@layout/dialog_about"
        android:title="@string/pref_about" />
```

Custom layout `dialog_about.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/privacy_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1px">

    </ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! can I prevent the system display Dialog box when aListPreference.entries is empty?

Comment: If you want to control its behavior, you have to extend it and override some methods. If you look at the `ListPreference` code, you can see it extends from `DialogPreference` and override `onPrepareDialogBuilder` which is called when building the dialog layout. You can change the dialog layout here base on the `entries`